# How to set Visual Studio Python's working directory to prevent error "No module named 'source'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio

My working dir isn't set right, so VS2019 running my Python3 module preprocessing_runner.py gets this error...
[image]

I did:  VS > Open a local folder > and selected top folder that contains a folder with Python module preprocessing_runner.  Top folder is:
C:\PRIMARY\WORK\wearable\OJWALCH_sleep_classifiers\
[image]

Then I had VS run module preprocessing_runner and got error:  "No module named 'source'"

I tried setting working directory in launch.vs.json but it didn't solve it:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append( os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/../../..'))
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough.  I just clarrified the question.  I need to know how to set the working directory in VS Python.